# Swift: 'use of unresolved identifier'- how to alter a variable and use that variable in different functions?

Tags: swift

I need to have this button that I have created (a blue button) alter a variable (named `playerMark`) that I create and use earlier in another code block in my code.

Here is where `playerMark` is introduced and is used:

```
func setImgforCircle(spot:Int, player:Int) {
        var playerMark = player == 1 ? "Red_x" : "Red_o"

    plays[spot] = player
    switch spot {
    case 1:
        circle1.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 2:
        circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 3:
        circle3.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 4:
        circle4.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 5:
        circle5.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 6:
        circle6.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 7:
        circle7.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 8:
        circle8.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 9:
        circle9.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

    default:
        circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    }

}
```

I have an IBAction named `blueBtnClicked` hooked up to my blue button that I need to execute:

```
playerMark = player == 1 ? "Blue_x" : "Blue_o"
```

but the console does not "remember" the variables (playerMark and player) and I get the error, 'use of unresolved identifier.' Here is the `blueBtnClicked` block:

```
@IBAction func blueBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        gameboard.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_gb")
        resultsView.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_results")
        colorsView.image = UIImage(named: "Blue_Colors")
        colorsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightTextColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        resetBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightTextColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
```

What can I do to to alter the playerMark variable when certain buttons are clicked? Please explain all answers very thoroughly as I am new to Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access a variable that is not in scope. Currently the scope of the playerMark variable is the setImgforCircle function, that means that playerMark is only accessible in setImgforCircle.

A solution can be to define the playerMark variable outside of the function as a class variable like so:

```
var playerMark: String?
```

The question mark makes this variable an optional so that you do not need to assign a value directly (the value is now nil)

to assign a value to playerMark you can simply say

```
playerMark = player == 1 ? "Red_x" : "Red_o"
```

you don't need to define it again with var.

Now the var is available anywhere in your class. You can read it by using `playerMark!`
The exclamation sign there means "I know that this value can be nil, but give me the value anyway".

The safe way to handle nil values of playerMark would be:

```
if playerMark {
   //access playerMark!
} else {
   // playerMark has no valid value, do something else
}
```

To get a greater understanding of swift i recommend reading "The Swift Programming Language" by Apple available for free on iBooks

Comment: Thank you that helped me a lot. I initialized a boolean named `blueBtn` the same way and made the IBAction set it to false and then used it as the if part (`if blueBtn == false`) in an if-else statement in my `setImgForCircle` function but no matter what, the else part executes. What's going on?

Comment: Read up on 'optionals' in swift. First check whether blueBtn is not nil by 'if blueBtn { if bluebBtn! == "somestring" } else { } }